# list all signals emitted from qt application

Tags: qt, logging, events, user-interaction, qcoreapplication

I've inherited a legacy qt gui application. One of first thing that I need to do is to create a log file where every user interaction is logged, like the click of a button, the edit of a QLineEdit and so on. This due to the fact that users apparently are not be able to tell how to reproduce specific bugs, so they want, when a bug is opened, to read this log file in order to check the steps that the user performed when he found it.

I've seen that it's possible to override the `notify` method in `QCoreApplication` in order to get all events, and it works, but it's not what I want, since it seems to manage only events of the operating system, like focusing etc, and it does not handle the emitting of signals.

Of course I can change the code and create a connection between, for example, a `textChanged` signals and a lambda that reports it, but in this case I will need to change all che code. Is there a way to achieve the same result in another way, without rewriting the most part of the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list all widgets in your application by using `QApplication::allWidgets()`.

Then, you could list all signals of each widget (with `QObject::metaObject()`) and connect them to a *logger*.

A quick example:

```
class Spy: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Spy();
public slots:
    void log();
};

void Spy::log()
{
    auto i = senderSignalIndex(); // The signal that fired this slot
    auto signal = sender()->metaObject()->method(i);
    qDebug() << sender() << signal.methodSignature();
}
```

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    Spy* spy = new Spy();

    QMetaMethod log = spy->metaObject()->method(spy->metaObject()->indexOfSlot("log()")); // in order to use the right QObject::connect signature

    for (auto widget: a.allWidgets())
    {
        auto metaObject = widget->metaObject();
        for (int i = 0; i != metaObject->methodCount(); ++i)
        {
            auto method = metaObject->method(i);
            if (method.methodType() != QMetaMethod::Signal) // We want to connect all the signals. We don't care about the other methods
                continue;

            widget->connect(widget, method, spy, log);
        }
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

You'll have to improve the code if you want to display the parameters.

You can also filter the objects to log only the significant signals (for ex, logging only the `clicked` signal from buttons)

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful.